# How can I select a different value in a column that contains a sublist in each iteration in python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, iteration

I have a data frame that has a column which contains lists in some rows. I would like to return a different value of those lists in each iteration.

In my main function I iterate row per row of the data frame adding and changing some values of the data frame. What I want to do with this particular column (that contains lists in some of the rows) is to select a different value of the list in each iteration.

Those rows that contain list in the column are always duplicated, so in the first iteration I would select the first value and in the second iteration I would select the second value.

So I have the following DF:

```
1, A, G, 35
2, C, G, 85
3, C, [A,G], 95
4, C, [A,G], 95
5, T, A, 78
6, T, C, 59
7, T, [A,C], 35
8, T, [A,C], 35
```

The desired output would be:

```
1, A, G, 35
2, C, G, 85
3, C, A, 95
4, C, G, 95
5, T, A, 78
6, T, C, 59
7, T, A, 35
8, T, C, 35
```

So in the iteration over row 3 I select the first value of the list  whereas in the iteration over row 4 I would get the second value of the list.

my code looks like this:

python

```
output= ouputfile
for line in dataframe:
    line = line.strip()
    linesplit = line.split(',')

    alt = linesplit[2]
    altsplit = alt.split(',')

    my_alt =[]
    if len(alsplit) == 1:
        my_alt.append(alt)
    else:
        my_alt.append(alt[n]) # n depending on the iteration

    output.write = ",".join(linesplit[0:2]+my_alt+[linesplit[3]])
```

I would prefer to avoid Pandas as it is gonna be integrated in a bigger program.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Rachael.

Comment: I think dataframe illustrates better my problem than talking of list of list of lists which is how I am treating my data.